# Sensor only those which are in a particular area in front of kinect Xbox 360?

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have to create a Interactive menu board. I am using **Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8**. Till now by using its in built sample projects(Control basis - Wpf)  I am able navigate (Control
kinecttilebutton). When I start running the program and nobody is in the room it works Perfectly but if there is more than one person in front of the kinect sensor the the hand (Kinect Mouse Pointer) move here and there .
Now my question 
**Is there any option kinect sensor only detect a person in a particular area (eg x=100-150,y=100-150,z=100-150)?**

**Edit**

Here is come code where it process the skeleton data.

```
 private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs skeletonFrameReadyEventArgs)
    {
        // Even though we un-register all our event handlers when the sensor
        // changes, there may still be an event for the old sensor in the queue
        // due to the way the KinectSensor delivers events.  So check again here.
        if (this.KinectSensor != sender)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = skeletonFrameReadyEventArgs.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (null != skeletonFrame)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Copy the skeleton data from the frame to an array used for temporary storage
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletons);

                    var accelerometerReading = this.KinectSensor.AccelerometerGetCurrentReading();

                    // Hand data to Interaction framework to be processed
                    this.interactionStream.ProcessSkeleton(this.skeletons, accelerometerReading, skeletonFrame.Timestamp);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // SkeletonFrame functions may throw when the sensor gets
                    // into a bad state.  Ignore the frame in that case.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Faced Same Problem By using below code I have track only one skeleton Which is closer to the sensor.and directly assign the closest skeleton to the main skeleton stream.

```
 private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs skeletonFrameReadyEventArgs)
    {
        Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = skeletonFrameReadyEventArgs.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null && this.skeletons != null)
            {
               //Console.WriteLine(skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength);
                skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];

                // Set skeleton datas from skeletonFrame
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletons);

                TrackClosestSkeleton();
                Skeleton[] singleSkeleton = new Skeleton[6];

                Skeleton skl=(from mno in this.skeletons where mno.TrackingState==SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked && mno.TrackingId==globalClosestID select mno).FirstOrDefault();
                if (skl == null)
                    return;

                //Creating an empty skkeleton
                Skeleton emptySkeleton = new Skeleton();

                singleSkeleton[0] = skl;        //Pass the Tracked skeleton with closestID
                singleSkeleton[1] = emptySkeleton;  //Passing Empty Skeleton
                singleSkeleton[2] = emptySkeleton;  //Passing Empty Skeleton
                singleSkeleton[3] = emptySkeleton;  //Passing Empty Skeleton
                singleSkeleton[4] = emptySkeleton;  //Passing Empty Skeleton
                singleSkeleton[5] = emptySkeleton;  //Passing Empty Skeleton

                this.snew.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(globalClosestID);
                var accelerometerReading = this.KinectSensor.AccelerometerGetCurrentReading();
                this.interactionStream.ProcessSkeleton(singleSkeleton, accelerometerReading, skeletonFrame.Timestamp);

            }
        }
    }

int globalClosestID = 0;
    private void TrackClosestSkeleton()
    {
        if (this.snew != null && this.snew.SkeletonStream != null)
        {
            if (!this.snew.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons)
            {
                this.snew.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons = true; // Ensure AppChoosesSkeletons is set
            }

            float closestDistance = 10000f; // Start with a far enough distance
            int closestID = 0;

            foreach (Skeleton skeleton in this.skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
            {
                if (skeleton.Position.Z < closestDistance)
                {
                    closestID = skeleton.TrackingId;
                    closestDistance = skeleton.Position.Z;
                }
            }

            if (closestID > 0)
            {
                this.snew.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(closestID); // Track this skeleton
                globalClosestID = closestID;
            }
        }
    }
```

check the above code it works for me.It may helpful to you.Here snew is the Kinectsensor.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to track the closest skeleton.

```
private void TrackClosestSkeleton()
  {
    if (this.kinect != null && this.kinect.SkeletonStream != null)
        {
        if (!this.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons)
        {
        this.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons = true; // Ensure AppChoosesSkeletons is set
        }

        float closestDistance = 10000f; // Start with a far enough distance
        int closestID = 0;

        foreach (Skeleton skeleton in this.skeletonData.Where(s => s.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
        {
        if (skeleton.Position.Z < closestDistance)
        {
          closestID = skeleton.TrackingId;
          closestDistance = skeleton.Position.Z;
        }
      }

      if (closestID > 0)
      {
        this.kinect.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(closestID); // Track this skeleton
      }
    }
  }
```

Get reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx)

Use it like this:

```
private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs skeletonFrameReadyEventArgs)
    {
        // Even though we un-register all our event handlers when the sensor
        // changes, there may still be an event for the old sensor in the queue
        // due to the way the KinectSensor delivers events.  So check again here.
        if (this.KinectSensor != sender)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = skeletonFrameReadyEventArgs.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (null != skeletonFrame)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Copy the skeleton data from the frame to an array used for temporary storage
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletons);
                    TrackClosesSkeleton();
                    var accelerometerReading = this.KinectSensor.AccelerometerGetCurrentReading();

                    // Hand data to Interaction framework to be processed
                    this.interactionStream.ProcessSkeleton(this.skeletons, accelerometerReading, skeletonFrame.Timestamp);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // SkeletonFrame functions may throw when the sensor gets
                    // into a bad state.  Ignore the frame in that case.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is just a quick edit so maybe you might rename some of your variables in order to make it fit well

Comment: This is the correct answer, you could also just order the skeletondata with an OrderByDescending(s => s.Position.Z).FirstOrDefault(). It's the same but shorter.

Comment: Thnx @florent for reply I found this KinectSensor.DepthStream.MaxDepth from where I can check the maximum depth of Can I do some thing by using this?

Comment: @kevin thnx for reply please help me.

Comment: What are thoses 100 ,150 etc dimensions? Are thoses the dimensions on your image or ? You don't need the depthstream for this.

Comment: @madanmohan you can set my proposition as an answer by clicking on the tick on its left

Comment: @kevin I want to limit the depth reading (I.E. Sensor will detect only those thins which are in the given range others will be Ignored)

Comment: Then the answer of Florent is correct. That's what it does.

Comment: but it doesn't help me.is there any other way to track,

Comment: Why doesn't it help? Could you update your post with some code that you have or have tried?

Comment: You're almost using the msdn SkeletonFrameReady method, so ?

Comment: Already read it and it didn't add anything that helped, you're really too stubborn for me I quit

Comment: just edited my post for the last time, mark it as an answer if it helped. Also learn how to correctly ask a question